# Are element IDs numbers in Webdrivers?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In the specs it seems to state that [element IDs are meant to be numbers](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-switch-to-frame). However, both Firefox and Chrome (in w3c mode) return something like `c87e08da-358e-45a8-b75c-c17cde92f606`. Chrome returns something like `45.32131231423424324324254245` when NOT in w3c mode.

So... are they meant to be numbers? Or, are those strings representing numbers? How do I cast them back to Integer?

Comment: What this number is is not important. What matters is its uniqueness  There were no rules before Selenium 3. The rule now states that this string needs to be a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Chrome is not yet compliant and build this number by incrementing it and by adding a float time-stamp.

Comment: I realise that. But the specs clearly state `If id is not null, a Number object, or an Object that represents a web element, return error with error code no such frame.` -- is this simply incorrect? Shall I open an issue with the specs?

Comment: What the spec requires and what the driver does are two different things. Keep in mind that the specification is a draft which is constantly evolving. What matters is whether the client and driver understand each-other.  In this case, it's more like a naming convention issue with no impact on the API. Thus I would't bother reporting it.

Comment: Note that from `If id is not null, a Number object, or an Object that represents a web element, return error with error code no such frame.`, the id refers to a DOM id, `Number object` refers to an index and webelement refers to the reference you are talking about. So there's no issue here.

Comment: @FlorentB. `id` isn't the DOM id, it's the name of the parameter accepted by the Switch To Frame method according to the spec. If `id` is null, then do X. If `id` is a Number object, then do Y... and so on. I agree with you, there is no issue here. It was a misunderstanding between `id` the parameter name as a Number object and the GUID of a referenced element.

Comment: @JeffC, you are right, thanks for pointing that out. The `id` in the statement indeed doesn't refer to the DOM id. Since Selenium 3 the protocol no longer supports frame switching by DOM id/name which is now [implemented by the client](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py#L67).

Comment: @DebanjanB Nope. Read what OP said and compare to what he referenced in the spec to see that it was misinterpreted. See Florent B's comment above to see that he agrees now that it was a misunderstanding. And now you can take the downvote off my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned `element IDs are meant to be numbers`, straight answer is **No**.

As Firefox (being W3C compliant) returns something like **c87e08da-358e-45a8-b75c-c17cde92f606** is a [**`UUID`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (`Universally Unique IDentifier`) is also known as [**`GUID`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (`Globally Unique IDentifier`) is the standardized format as per the [**`W3C WebDriver Specs`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#terminology) to identify an element following the [**`RFC4122`**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122)

### **`UUID`**

An **`UUID`** is an identifier which is unique across both space and time, with respect to the space of all `UUIDs`.  Hence an `UUID` can be used for multiple purposes, from tagging objects with an extremely short lifetime, to reliably identifying very persistent objects across a network.

The internal representation of a `UUID` is a specific sequence of bits in memory. To accurately represent a UUID as a URN, it is necessary to convert the bit sequence to a string representation. Each field is treated as an integer and has its value printed as a zero-filled hexadecimal digit string with the most significant digit first.

### Example

A typical string representation of a `UUID` is : **`uuid`**`:`**`f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6`**

### Generating UUIDs

Three algorithms are generally used to maintain uniqueness of generated `UUIDs`:

- An algorithm that leverages the unique values of IEEE 802 MAC addresses which are available on network-connected hosts.
- The second algorithm uses pseudo-random number generators.
- The third uses cryptographic hashing and application-specific text strings.

Hence, the `UUIDs` generated according to these mechanisms will be always unique from all other `UUIDs` that have been or will be assigned and no question of `casting` them back to **Integer** till the **`WebDriver`** variants successfully negotiates the **`UUIDs`** with the respective pair of `Browsers`.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two different things. The spec is referring to a number that is an index into the collection of frames on the page. Your examples are GUIDs that are just unique identifiers of referenced elements on the page. The two are not the same nor interchangeable.

From the link you provided (under #5),

> id is a Number object

This is in the context of using Switch To Frame. This allows the API to accept a number (which is an index into the collection of frames) to access a frame. For example, in Java you would use

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0)
```

where `0` is the `id` which is a "number object" which is referred to in the portion of the spec you referenced. This would switch the driver context into the first (0th) frame on the page. There are other ways to switch to a frame, e.g. using a known web element. This is the third method listed in the spec (also under #5)

> id represents a web element

The spec then defines how to handle the various cases for a web element.

The numbers that you refer to in your question are just GUIDs or unique identifiers to currently referenced web elements as FlorentB described in comments. You can't pass these numbers/GUIDs into the API to switch frames, etc.

If you want to see how this is implemented in Java, you can see the docs [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html).