# Does using selenium change the token of the session?

Tags: selenium, python-3.7, selenium-firefoxdriver

i am writing a tool to check mac address online with selenium i managed to find the input and the submit but when i ask for the results it print the session id and the token

```
import selenium 
## set up options
options = Options()
options.headless=True
browser.Firefox(options, exceutable_path=r"geckodriver_path")
browser.get("site-URL")
## mac address sent to site

elem = browser.find_element_by_id('result')
elemnt  = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#results-log')
print (elem)
print (elemnt)
```

the output is some session info

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="289e304328d8a7900f7003d4ed6530be",        element="f807a2e7-8895-4e8d-b7af-ce3d27fbf897")>
```

i need to get the result that is on the site

Answer (score 0):

You saw it right.

- The variable **elem** is a WebElement identified through `browser.find_element_by_id('result')`
- The variable **elemnt** is a WebElement identified through `browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#results-log')`

Printing the element will be in the following format:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="289e304328d8a7900f7003d4ed6530be",        element="f807a2e7-8895-4e8d-b7af-ce3d27fbf897")>
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Are element IDs numbers in Webdrivers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404087/are-element-ids-numbers-in-webdrivers/48409971#48409971)

Comment: can i bypass this to get a result log or something useful other than the session number